# Why store.getState() doesn't update in reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, redux-toolkit, global-state

Does anyone know why though through the "useSelector" hook, the updated state is available, but the store.getState() doesn't update?

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    baseUrl: "http://example.com/" 
}

function changeToLocal(state) {
    return {...state, baseUrl: "https://localhost:345345/"}
}
function changeToGlobal(state) {
    return { ...state, baseUrl: "http://example.com/"}
}


const ApiConfig = createSlice({
    name: 'changeBaseURL',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        changeToLocal,
        changeToGlobal,
    }
})

export const {
    changeToLocal: changeToLocalAction,
    changeToGlobal: changeToGlobalAction,
} = ApiConfig.actions

export default ApiConfig.reducer;
```

Here after dispatching, through the "useSelector" hook, the updated state is recieved:

```js
const Header = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch())
    const CurrentBaseURL= useSelector(state => state.changeBaseURL.baseUrl)
    console.log(" ~ file: header.jsx ~ line 11 ~ Header ~ CurrentBaseURL", CurrentBaseURL)
    const changeBaseURl = (e) => {
        if (e.target.value === "local") {
            dispatch(changeToLocalAction())
        } else if (e.target.value === "global"){
            dispatch(changeToGlobalAction())
        }
    }
...
```

:

But when I wanted to use the updated baseURL in my APIConfig file, I realized that it didn't update:

```js
import { Toast } from '../../helpers/Toast';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../../redux/store';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "htttp://example.com",
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: { "x-Custom-Header": "foobar" }
    })
    instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        if (response.headers["token-user"]) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.headers["token-user"]);
        }
        if (response.data && response.data.statusIcon && response.data.status) {
            Toast(response.data.statusIcon, response.data.status);
        }
        return response;
    }, err => {
        const expectErrors = err.response && err.response > 400 && err.response.status < 500;
        if (!expectErrors) {
            console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);

    });
    export default instance;
```

The above config is used like so:

```js
import Api from '../../../utils/request/api/Api'

export const GetDisposablePassword = (nationalCode) => {
    return Api.post(`api/Auth/GetDisposablePassword`, { nationalCode })
};
```

Does anyone know how to handle this problem by a principal method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using locagStorage instead of `@reduxjs/toolkit` like so:

```js
import { currentBaseURL, localBaseURL, officialBaseURL } from '../../utils/request/Request';


const Header = () => {
    const changeBaseURl = (e: any) => {
        if (e.target.value === "local") {
            localStorage.setItem("baseURL", JSON.stringify({
                key: e.target.value,
                value: localBaseURL   
            }));
        } else if (e.target.value === "current") {
            localStorage.setItem("baseURL", JSON.stringify({
                key: e.target.value
                value: currentBaseURL
            }));
        } else if (e.target.value === "official") {
            localStorage.setItem("baseURL", JSON.stringify({
                key: e.target.value,
                value: officialBaseURL
            }));
        }
    }
...
```

And in file `Request`:

```js
export const currentBaseURL = window.location.origin;
export const officialBaseURL = "https://exampel.example";
export const localBaseURL = "https://localhost:7215/";

var baseURL = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('baseURL') || '{}');
    if (isEmpty(baseURL)) {
            baseURL = currentBaseURL;
        }
    } else {
        baseURL = baseURL.value;
    }
    
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: baseURL,
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: { "x-Custom-Header": "foobar" }
    })
    instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        if (response.headers["token-user"]) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", response.headers["token-user"]);
        }
        if (response.data && response.data.statusIcon && response.data.status) {
            Toast(response.data.statusIcon, response.data.status);
        }
        return response;
    }, err => {
        const expectErrors = err.response && err.response > 400 && err.response.status < 500;
        if (!expectErrors) {
            console.log(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);

    });
    export default instance
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess here is that you config file is not your application, wrapped by the store provider.

EDIT - To clarify :

```
const state = store.getState();
```

Can only be used inside a component mounted in your application that is wrapped by the store provider.

Since your .config file is not wrapped and mounted in your application and wrapped by your provider, it is normal to get an undefined value.

Comment: Yes, not wrapped because the config file will be imported wherever needed.

Comment: The problem is here, you can't acess to your store and its values if you are not inside your store provider.

Comment: i have updated my answer, i hope you will get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you @johan-petrikovsky for your guidance, but the problem is how can I make a dynamic baseUrl, considering that my APIConfig file is included an instance of "axios.create" and its "interceptors" with its "return". I want to handle this problem by a principal method.